# How to set the location for the center of a shape in Photoshop, not the top left corner?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When setting the location of a shape in Photoshop, by default you can type in the (x,y) coordinates of the top left corner of the bounding box of that shape.
[image]

Is there any way to configure photoshop so that I can instead type in the coordinates of the *center* of that bounding box?

Obviously I can do the math, and subtract half of the W and H of the object from my desired center-coordinates. It actually gets slightly more complicated though, because while the object pictured above is 320x320, it is *actually* 324x324 because the stroke is 4px wide and centered on the circle. It gets tedious.

Or failing that, what is the easiest way to get the *center* of a shape to a specific set of coordinates?

Comment: You can hold the Option/Alt key when drawing to start from center. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible options.

Place a horizontal and vertical guide to pinpoint a specific location, i.e. where the guides intersect. If you need precise accuracy, you can place new guides numerically by doing *View > Guides > New Guide* and type in the value where you want the guides to be. Make sure Snapping and Smart Guides are on. Then do one of the following:

1. A shape's centre should be able to snap to where the guides intersect. You may have to zoom in or out a bit to get it to work.

or

2. Mouse over where the guides intersect, then as Scott suggests in his comment, you could begin drawing a new shape, and then hold down <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> as you drag. This should centre it on the guide intersection.

or

3. Smart guides often work better if you first draw a shape like a square (using method 2 above), to use as a helper shape. Then you can click and drag your shape over this to centre it using snapping. You can delete the square afterwards.